# Torsion in homology of a subset $E \subset \Bbb R^n$ with $n≤2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

> For $n \in \{1,2\}$, is there a subset $E \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that one of its (singular) homology groups $H_k(E)$ has an element of finite order?

According to [Is the fundamental group of every subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ torsion free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36279/), $\pi_1(E)$ is torsion-free, but $H_1(E) = \pi_1(E)/[\pi_1(E),\pi_1(E)]$ [could](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546624) have torsion elements. According to [this link on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4478/) (or [this one](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/torsion_for_subsets_of_mathbb_r_3)), a theorem of Eda states that this is impossible to find such subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ with $n=2$ (then also for $n=1$). [By the way, I'm not sure to know from this MO thread if the answer is completely known for $n=3$].

I don't have a copy of this article, but the title "Fundamental group of subsets of the plane" suggests that it only proves the fact that $\pi_1(E)$ is torsion-free. I don't see how this can answer my question on homology groups. Related questions: [(1)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189323), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155421).

Thank you for your comments!

Comment: If $E$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ which is compact and locally-connected (aka sufficiently nice), then Alexander duality will tell you $E$ has no torsion on $H_1$ (and $H_2$ vanishes).

Comment: Related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281426/

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about Eda's paper, but [Fischer-Zastrow](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0512343.pdf) prove that for any subset of a closed oriented surface $X$, $\pi_1(X)$ is (many things, but in particular) locally free: that every finitely-generated subgroup is free. But if there were a nonzero element $x$ with $x^n \in [\pi_1, \pi_1]$ (but $x$ not so), we could write $x^n = [g_1, h_1] \cdots [g_n, h_n]$. This would provide a nontrivial relation on the subgroup generated by $x, [g_i, h_i]$, since $x$ cannot possibly be expressed in terms of the latter elements alone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So this disproves the existence of closed subsets $E \subset \Bbb R^n$ (with $n=1$ or $n=2$) such that $H_1(E)$ has torsion (but gives no information about $H_k(E)$ for $k≥2$), is it right?

Comment: @Watson Sorry, I guess I missed the part of your question about $H_k(E)$. That is almost certainly always zero, but I don't have a proof right now.

Comment: No problem! This already gives an excellent answer for $H_1(E)$, where $E$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^n$ ($n≤2$).

Comment: @Watson: A path-connected subset of $\Bbb R$ is an interval, which you can use to conclude the general result that $H_i = 0$ for $i > 0$ in that case.

Comment: @Watson Two things: 1) in my comment above I mean for the case of subsets of $\Bbb R$, and 2) The result of this answer does not actually assume that the subset is closed!

Comment: 1) ok 2) Ah, yes! I misinterpreted the word "closed". Thank you for the clarification.